# Online exception:Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, download, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

We are talking about a software that I implemented (client and server sides), sometimes I get the following error while downloading.  Is it something from the server side or the client side?

** The timeout for the httpwebrequest is one hour, so its not about the timeout.

> Online exception:Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was  forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't having a badly handles exception while returning the answer. We had some hidden non logged exceptions leading to the same result.

Comment: no because, I dont think so, because I faced that error more than once, and one of them was from a big name in the IT field servers

Comment: Do you have the request or the client in a using block?  I had issues with that once where I needed to let everything complete and then only call dispose/close at the very end after everything else had been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities :

- Firewall blocking connections in some cases, due to configurations.
- Like maldevane commented, you are disposing the object before
  download completes.